# a result from rank-nullity theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Suppose that we have $m$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n,$ $v_1,v_2,...,v_m$, such that

$X^Tv_i=0,~\forall i.$

Prove that if $\dim(\langle v_1,...,v_m\rangle)=l$ then the answers of above equation ($X$) is $n−l$ dimension.

Can anyone prove this with Rank-nullity theorem?

Comment: If you mean $Xv_1, Xv_2,...$ etc, then that isn't necessarily true. For instance, $X$ can be the zero matrix.

Comment: no I mean the dot product of them

Comment: $X$ can still be the zero vector...

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the $\dim (\text{nul}(V))$ with $V = (v_1,\ldots,v_m)$

Comment: yes, but is this my answer?

Comment: Yes it is. You can use it to prove what youwant

Comment: can you explain more

Comment: please help me:((